# What are the effective ways to work Node js with a large JSON file of 600 MB and more?

Tags: node.js, json

What are the effective ways to work Node js with a large JSON file of 600 MB and more?

My partner gives me from his REST API wery large JSON file. 600mb,  1000mb

Its structure is as follows

> { nameid1:[list id,....], nameid2:[list id,....], }

[list id,....] - An array with ID can be up to hundreds of millions of records.

Now to work with such files I use the following sequence of actions.

1. I save it to hard drive
2. With the sed command, from a single-line file, I make it multi-line

Example

> exec (`sed -i 's /', '/', '\ n / g' file.json)

3. I work directly with the file using readline

I tried to use JSONStream but it causes FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

```
function getStream() {
    let jsonData = __dirname + '/jsonlarge/file.json',

    stream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData, {
        encoding: 'utf8'
    })

    parser = JSONStream.parse('*');
    stream.pipe(parser)
    parser.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('received:', data);
    });
}
```

Example structure json file

```
{"Work":"12122001","name":"Regist","world":[{"name":"000000","point":"rfg","Content":["3202b9a3fba","121323","2343454","45345543","354534534"]}, {"name":"000000","point":"rfg","Content":["3202b","121323","2343454","45345543","354534534"]}, {"name":"000000","point":"rfg","Content":["320","121323","2343454","45345543","354534534"]}]}
```

Maybe someone knows a faster way to work with such files.

Thanks

Comment: Show how you're using JSONStream, because most likely you're using it wrong. When it's used correctly you will avoid that error. The only way to deal with large JSON like yours is using transform streams, like the JSONStream package, otherwise you endup with the whole JSON in memory, and you will exhaust all the memory available.

Comment: No, nobody blocks me. I just download these files for processing via GET request.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using, otherwise it's impossible to fix it. Also if you provide the JSON will be helpful.

Comment: `function getStream() {
      let jsonData = __dirname + '/jsonlarge/file.json',
            stream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData, {encoding: 'utf8'})
            parser = JSONStream.parse('*');
            stream.pipe(parser)
            parser.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('received:', data);
             });   
     }`

Comment: Update your answer with that code. And if you can send a link of the JSON I'll give you a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not throw a link to the file. But I have shown the JSON File of its structure.

Comment: If this is a series of JSON documents, one per line, then the streaming approach will work, you'll just have to be careful how you implement it. Split by lines first, then pipe that to something that converts lines to parsed JSON objects, and so on.